# Custom style for all Edit Texts in the application

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I have an Android application which uses Material design theme with backward compatibility through `AppCompat`.

There are multiple `Textview's` and `EditText's` in my application. I would like the same properties to be applied to all these `TextView's` and `EditText's` across the application. In order to achieve this, i have defined a custom style as shown below:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="ParentTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ArabicTheme" parent="ParentTheme">
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/arabicEditText</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/arabicTextView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="arabicEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    </style>

    <style name="arabicTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    </style>
```

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` file under the `<Application>` tag, i have set `android:theme="@style/ArabicTheme"`.

Below is the output of the activity:
[image]

As seen in the above output, the Style is being applied to `TextView` only. However, The same is not being applied to `EditText`.

Incase, if i explicitly specify these properties to the EditText in the corresponding Actitivy's xml as shown below:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />
```

i.e I have explicitly added `android:ellipsize="end"` and `android:gravity="right"` to the `<EditText>`, and only then the output is as expected:

[image]

Like i said, i have multiple TextView's and EditText's and i cannot explicitly add these properties to all of them. So, is there a way i can achieve this using Styles or any other approach? Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: You can give edit text style using java code Typeface like(regular,bold,normal)

Comment: @GowthamanM: Even in this case, i need to explicitly do this for all the edit texts in my application. The solution i am looking for is, set it once and the same property must be applied for all the EditTexts in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Just remove `android:` from the editText's attribute name:

```
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/arabicEditText</item>
```

I cannot explain this though. I guess appCompat things don't reuse android attributes, but add another ones with similiar names. Same goes with `colorPrimary`, `srcCompat` and others.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Any idea removing android: from the textViewStyle would give a compilation error?

Comment: I suppose that there's no textViewStyle redefined outside of android namespace

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing this

```
public class LightEditText extends android.widget.EditText{

    public LightEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFont();

    }

    public LightEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFont();
    }

    public LightEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setFont();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public LightEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        setFont();
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to set the given font to the TextView.
     */
    private void setFont() {
        Typeface typeface = TypefaceCache.get(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        setTypeface(typeface);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Then inside your xml file

```
<com.packagename.LightEditText
 android:id="@+id/edtTaskName"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Do the above method for setting common properties(fontType,style..etc) to editext